# the probability of successful transmission of a data vector over a graph network

Tags: algorithm, graph, probability, max-flow

I have been looking for an answer to the given question. The other details provided are:
given each links in the graph with capacity >0 is p and probability of links with capacity<0 is 1-p. What is the probability that a data vector like say {1,2,3,4} will get successfully transmitted from node 1 to node 5.

I know there is the concept of max- flow for these kind of problems but I do not understand still the probability of successful transmission through such a network.

second question: before starting to look for max-flow concepts. I started out thinking given a start and destination node one can simply do a BFS to find out the many possible paths from the source node to the destination node and keep a tap on them (I realize if there are infinite paths it becomes an exponential time algorithms with huge space complexity but say it's a fairly finite network). Then in order to cal the P(successful transmission) can it be approached in the following way?

say the #of paths from node 1 to node 5 is 4
then 
P(successful transmission between node1 and node 5 is)= P(path1)+p(path2)+p(path3)+p(path4)-p(path intersections) where,

P(intersections) are  those probabilities where two or more paths may share edges like:
p(intersections)=p(4c2)+p(4c3)-p(4c4)
where 4cr--> no of no of paths where r<=4.

Also p(path#)=p^no of edges in that path. Is my approach right? Also if it's okay to think this way how can I expand this to infinite path possibility?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you.

Comment: Your approach is wrong (it can lead to probabilities > 1) and some of your language is unclear. Is the "data vector" one message or four? Must a message take only one path, or can it "split up" to have a better chance of reaching the destination? Is "capacity" something we must worry about?...

Comment: this was an interview question, I believe we don't really have to worry about capacity since a no capacity path will automatically be weeded out. the message can split out over probable paths and that's why I am inclined to think we need to take the union of all paths probable for the event of successful transmission to happen. Each individual probablity is <1 then how come this system may give rise to prob>1? l was following the simple theory of (a union b)=p(a)+p(b)-p(a intersection b). Could you provide a little more insight as why my approach would be wrong this way?

Comment: and yes data vector is a unit of 4 which can split up during transmission.

Comment: What do you mean by "transmit a data vector over a graph network"? What do you mean by "given each links in the graph with capacity >0 is p and probability of links with capacity<0 is 1-p"? Is your question asking to find the probability of two points having a path between them in a random graph where the edge probability is p?

Comment: @Anonymous yes it's asking what is the probability of transmission between two given nodes. Given each edge which has capacity > 0 also having a prob p and capacity =0 edges having prob 1-p.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question of programming but of probability.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a simple graph, A->B->C. And suppose p=0.9 for each edge. The probability of a message passing from A to C is **not** 2p=1.8, so `P(path) = p * number of edges` is not correct. The correct probability is P = p<sup>2</sup> = 0.81

If there are two such paths, A->B->C and A->D->C (p=0.9 for all edges), and we send *one* copy of the message down one path, the probability of its arrival is 0.81, but if we can send a copy down *each* path, the probability is *not* P=1.62; the probabilities of non-intersecting paths do not add. If we send one copy down each path, P=0.9639, and if we split the message into two parts and send one part down each path, the probability that the whole message will arrive is P=0.6561

You must understand the basics of probability before this will make any sense. There is no short-cut for this, we can't give you "the answer", you have to study it.

Comment: Hi, I do get your point that it's 1-(prob of always failure) in case of sending copies and then in case of diving and sending it works like the chain rule where both events has to be successful to make a successful event. I am interested to know why shouldn't we think of each probable path transmission as individual events and look for union of all the events to happen for a success. What am I missing here? Also yes I typed it wrong I meant P(path) to be P(path) = p ^ number of edges

Comment: @Beta I agree with what you write, but I think this is a comment rather than an answer to the question.

Comment: @user3302611: Please check your question for other such errors, lest we all waste time.

Comment: @Anonymous: [shrug] The question more-or-less asks "is this approach correct?", and I answered "no, and here's why...".

Comment: @Beta I think that my approach should be correct too as is yours and yield the same answer as yours and it will not be greater than 1. For example: P(P1 union P2) = P(p1)+P(p2)-P(p1 intersection p2). Since P1 and P2 are independent events and not mutually exclusive, P(p1 union P2)= P(p1)*P(p2) therefore the answer to the example you gave :              P(p1 union p2)= 0.81 + 0.81 - (0.81*0.81) = 0.9639. It's just two different ways of thinking! what you suggest is 1-P(event always fails)=P(either or both event succeeds)= P(event1 union event2). However your's is computationally efficient.

Comment: @user3302611: That's quite different from what you wrote in your question. At this point I think I should say that I don't know whether your approach is correct, because I can't tell what it is.